# Where to put custom java file of hazelcast custom mapstore implementation

Tags: hazelcast

I have implemented a custom MaStore for hazelcast. But I have no idea where to put this .java file ,so that hazelcast will build it and pick it.

Any help in this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the [sample](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/distributed-map/mapstore) here, see how the PersonMapStore class is located inside project hierarchy and it's mentioned in the configuration file.